# what assert do in a class service in Jest

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, tdd

I have a question related the way of test a service class that I've created:

**serverRequest.service.js**

```
import { get } from 'axios';

exports const serverRequest = {

  get: (url, params) => {
     try {
        return get(url, params)
     } catch() {
        return new Error('server error');
     }
  }
}
```

**serverRequest.service.spec.js**

```
import { get } from 'axios';
import { serverRequest } from './serverRequest.service';

jest.mock('axios', () => ({
  get: jest.fn(),
}));

//This part I am not sure if it is needed
const spyServerRequestGet = jest.spyOn(serverRequest, 'get');

describe('server request get', async () => {
    const data = { data: {} };
    get.mockReturnValue(data)

    const result = await serverRequest.get('http://server', null);

    // I'm not sure if this asserts have sense in here
    expect(spyServerRequestGet).toHaveBeenCalledWith('http://server', null)
    expect(spyServerRequestGet).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    
    // this should be OK
    expect(get).toHaveBeenCalledWith('http://server', null)
    expect(result).toEqual(data);
});
```

My question it is about this part:

```
// I'm not sure if this asserts have sense in here
expect(spyServerRequestGet).toHaveBeenCalledWith('http://server', null)
expect(spyServerRequestGet).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

I'm spying the method that I want test because I think that the way of the method it is used it is stuff for being tested.

**What do you think about this assertion?**

**It is ok spying the same method that I want test?**

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to spy the methods which you want to test. Because you know what method(`serverRequest.get`) the current test case is testing.

You should spy the objects and their methods(`axios.get`) called by the method you want to test. Then, you can make assertions for them to check if they are called or not to ensure that your code logic and executed code branch are as expected.

E.g.

`serverRequest.service.js`:

```js
import { get } from 'axios';

export const serverRequest = {
  get: (url, params) => {
    try {
      return get(url, params);
    } catch (err) {
      return new Error('server error');
    }
  },
};
```

`serverRequest.service.spec.js`

```js
import { get } from 'axios';
import { serverRequest } from './serverRequest.service';

jest.mock('axios', () => ({
  get: jest.fn(),
}));

describe('server request get', () => {
  afterAll(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });
  it('should pass', async () => {
    const data = { data: {} };
    get.mockResolvedValue(data);

    const result = await serverRequest.get('http://server', null);
    expect(get).toHaveBeenCalledWith('http://server', null);
    expect(result).toEqual(data);
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/64069204/serverRequest.service.spec.js
  server request get
    ✓ should pass (5ms)

--------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File                      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
--------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files                 |       80 |      100 |      100 |       80 |                   |
 serverRequest.service.js |       80 |      100 |      100 |       80 |                 8 |
--------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.035s, estimated 9s
```